# java.lang.VerifyError: Uninitialized object exists on backward branch Kafka Win-10

Tags: apache-kafka

I am facing an issue when starting Kafka server in my local machine (Windows 10) using the command

> .\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat .\config\server.properties

I am getting the error shown below. I already have zookeeper server running.

```
[2020-07-27 16:08:05,144] INFO Registered kafka:type=kafka.Log4jController MBean (kafka.utils.Log4jControllerRegistration$)
[2020-07-27 16:08:05,394] ERROR Exiting Kafka due to fatal exception (kafka.Kafka$)
java.lang.VerifyError: Uninitialized object exists on backward branch 79
Exception Details:
  Location:
    scala/util/matching/Regex.unapplySeq(Lscala/util/matching/Regex$Match;)Lscala/Option; @126: goto
  Reason:
    Error exists in the bytecode
  Bytecode:
    0000000: 2bb6 00b5 c700 07b2 0080 b02b b600 b8b6
    0000010: 00b9 2ab6 004b 4d59 c700 0b57 2cc6 000d
    0000020: a700 752c b600 bd99 006e b200 3757 bb00
    0000030: 5559 b200 5a57 2bb6 00be 3ebb 0060 59b7
    0000040: 0064 3a04 1904 1db9 006a 0200 0336 0515
    0000050: 051d a200 2f2b 1505 0460 b600 bf3a 0819
    0000060: 0801 3a08 3a07 1907 013a 073a 0619 0419
    0000070: 06b6 0072 5701 3a06 1505 0460 3605 a7ff
    0000080: d119 04b9 0076 0100 c000 7801 3a04 013a
    0000090: 06b7 007b b02a 2bb6 00b5 b600 c1b0
  Stackmap Table:
    same_frame(@11)
    full_frame(@35,{Object[#2],Object[#24],Object[#62]},{Object[#62]})
    same_frame(@42)
    full_frame(@79,{Object[#2],Object[#24],Object[#62],Integer,Object[#96],Integer},{Uninitialized[#46],Uninitialized[#46]})
    full_frame(@129,{Object[#2],Object[#24],Object[#62],Integer,Object[#96],Integer},{Uninitialized[#46],Uninitialized[#46]})
    chop_frame(@149,3)

        at scala.collection.StringOps$.r$extension(StringOps.scala:843)
        at kafka.cluster.EndPoint$.<clinit>(EndPoint.scala:29)
        at kafka.server.Defaults$.<clinit>(KafkaConfig.scala:79)
        at kafka.server.KafkaConfig$.<clinit>(KafkaConfig.scala:961)
        at kafka.metrics.KafkaMetricsConfig.<init>(KafkaMetricsConfig.scala:33)
        at kafka.metrics.KafkaMetricsReporter$.startReporters(KafkaMetricsReporter.scala:62)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable$.fromProps(KafkaServerStartable.scala:33)
        at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:68)
        at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be an issue with your `JAVA_HOME` environment variable. Make sure your `JAVA_HOME` has the path to your `JRE` (Java runtime environment) and not `JDK` (Java Development Kit).

Just to be on the safe side, not sure if it's actually causing an incompatibility consider using `1.8.0_241` for `Scala` supporting libraries.

```
e.g. my JAVA_HOME environment variable: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_241
```